# Excel Range in Word Document Does not keep Formatting after updating link

Tags: c#, excel, ms-word, interop

I have a Word file with several Linked tables from an excel file inside it. When I update the link though, the table inside the file does not keep the table formatting.

If I do it manually by hand through Word, the formatting stays.

I try to do it programmatically with the following code:

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

public void LaunchWord()
{
    WordApp = new Word.Application();
    Document = WordApp.Documents.Open(PathToTemporaryTemplate, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Word.WdOpenFormat.wdOpenFormatAuto, Missing.Value, true, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
    Fields = Document.Fields;
    Document.UpdateStylesOnOpen = false;
    Document.Activate();
}
```

Then I try to update the links like this:

```
public void ChangeLinks(string pathToNewExcel)
{
    var links = Fields.Cast<Word.Field>().AsEnumerable().Where(c => c.LinkFormat != null).ToList();

    foreach (Word.Field field in links)
    {
        //field.LinkFormat.AutoUpdate = false;
        //field.DoClick();
        field.LinkFormat.SourceFullName = pathToNewExcel;
        //field.OLEFormat.Activate();
        field.OLEFormat.PreserveFormattingOnUpdate = true;
        field.LinkFormat.Update();
        //field.LinkFormat.SavePictureWithDocument = true;  
        //field.UpdateSource();
        field.Update();
     }
     Document.Save();
 }
```

With comments are all the additional things that I have tried, but did not work.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of tries and questions, I came to the following solution:

```
foreach (Word.Field field in links)
{
    field.Code.Text = field.Code.Text.Replace(oldPath, newPath);
    field.Update();
}
```

It's a little tricky how to pinpoint the path of the excel file inside the Code.Path property, but it will keep all formatting after updating the field.